# two jquery doesnt work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

i have two jquery(can increase), one of them masterpage and the other is in contentpage... first i added contentpage query(it is an horizontal accordion menu) and it worked perfectly then i need second one (to get collapsible panel title position) in masterpage... but after added second, both of them didnt work... what is the problem exactly...

samples code

this is first added to make horizontal accordion menu in my contentpage :

```
     <script src="jquery.zaccordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.zaccordion.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


/*In MasterPage to Horizontal accordion*/
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript">
/*Second query plugin*/

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#featured").zAccordion({
                width: 600,
                height: 260,
                tabWidth: 75
            });
        });
    </script>
```

second added code to change position of title panel of collapsible panel according to expand and collapse..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var bodyHeight = $(document).height();
            var panelHeight = $('#pnlSearchContent').height(); --CP content panel height
            var panelHeightPosition = bodyHeight - panelHeight;
            $('#pnlSearchTitle').offset().top = panelHeightPosition;   -- CP Title panel final position
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you refering jQuery file twice?

Comment: Can you post the two scripts so people can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: We can't give you the solution until you can give specific error messages and/or code samples

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "two jquery", two different versions of jQuery or two lines of jQuery?? I think it would be helpful to provide some code.

Comment: editted : i  added code... @rahul no... two seperate query from different files @JohnP there is not any error, its just doesnt work ...  @Wolfram two different query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` from your code, you already include `jquery-1.5.js` from external website.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using 2 jQuery plugins and including Jquery js file twice (once for each plugin)

You must include Jquery js file only once that will be consumed by both the plugin js files.

When you view source, your html should look like this:

```
//this is the actual jquery javascript file.
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugin-1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugin-2.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: thx @goths.. but there is not twice trust me i editted question(again) added plugins,